# How To Clear App Of Beta To Post On App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode9-beta

I have published an app on the iOS app store and I have now got the xcode 9 beta on my mac. I opened the app project with the beta for around 5-10 mins and made a few changes but the beta was being buggy so I decided to go back to the stable xcode 8. However, now whenever I try to add my app update to the app store, it won't let me as it says I have used the beta and apps can't be posted on the app store made with a beta (even though I barely used it)

Is there any way to clear my project and make it free of beta files etc. I don't really know how this works but would really like to post my app update.

Thanks in advance

Luke

Comment: if you are using Git you can easily revert back your changes.

Comment: Try doing a clean build (which you should always do anyway before testing).

Comment: @rmaddy I have done a clean build but still get the error. Any ideas?